# JSONSerialization.jsonObject

Tags: json, swift, swift3

Раньше метод

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
```

возвращал `AnyObject`, что с легкостью конвертировалось в `Dictionary`. B Swift 3 имеем след.

```
open class func jsonObject(with data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any
```

> Как мне конвертировать `Any` в `Dictionary` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного недопоняли. Возвращает он по-прежнему `AnyObject`, а вот выбрасывает `Any` в случае исключения.

Для получения `JSON` пропиcываете:

```
let object: AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: options)
```

(ну и ошибки обработать `do-catch`)